# Suddenly the connection between excel and access doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access-2016

I have a program developed for more than 15 years in excel VBA.
This program is stored in an excel book and is connected to an access database located on a file server, which stores the budget data for our activity, customer information, etc...
This program connects to the access database using sql queries. These queries are debugged for a long time and do not present errors.
Currently there are 5 users using the program and it works correctly for all of them.
One day it suddenly started giving me an error. Only for me and not to the other users.
The error it gives me is when making a query to the database. Not a specific query, it can be any query. A query that works correctly then stops working. A query that in another computer works fine in mine gives an error.
I have error handling and the error it gives is:

```
err.description -> Unspecified error
err.number -> -2147467259
```

The problem is that I don't know where to look for the error.
As the program had worked correctly on my current computer for more than two years, I suspect that there has been some update of OneDrive, or Office 365, or the Avast antivirus, etc... that interferes with the connection between excel and access.
I have formatted the computer, installed only Office 365 alone and it continues to give an error!! That's why I suspect it might be something to do with my Office365 account's security settings or similar.
My feeling is that it allows you to make the connection with access at first but after a short time something is activated and prevents the connection.

Comment: Please read this article on debugging: http://cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx

Comment: A critical bit of missing information: Where does the Access Database live? Can you open it manually in Access?

Comment: Be aware of an issue related to MsAccess files accessed over file-shares:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/error-in-access-when-opening-a-database-on-a-network-file-share-6cbc1560-62c2-46e7-9980-d079a46f5acc
Introduced by an update in Nov-Dec-2021.

Comment: Your error -2147467259 or 0x80004005 as Hex is a generic connection or file error, and  consistent with the issue advised by userMT. Try searching the hex error for recent reports say in a 'date range' of the last two months.

Comment: @HackSlash thank you for responding. The database is living on a server. And yes, I can open the database manually. The string connection I am using is this: "sconnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source= " & "\IMPULSO 6\00 EMPRESA\00 SOFTWARE\00 MINISAP\00 BD\bbdd_minisap.accdb" & ";"

Comment: Finally I could correct the error. But what I had to do is turn back to the latest version of Excel (14729.20194) and onedrive (22.002.0103.0004). That means that in new features that they introduce in the new updates makes crash the access to an access database? May be this is related with the issue that @userMT says?